# How do I load some MP3 files onto an iPod nano, as podcasts?

Tags: macos, sonoma, ipod-nano

I have a 7th gen iPod nano, and I have some MP3 files. I would like to copy them over to the iPod, so that they appear in the Podcasts menu.

So far, I have tried looking for a way to subscribe to a local directory on my macbook in the Podcasts application, with no success. I also tried copying the files into the Podcasts directory on the iPod, but they don't seem to appear anywhere in the menu system.

How do I solve this?

Comment: A podcast is much more than just an MP3. There’s additional metadata and an xml file that needs to accompany the audio file so that you can accomplish what you’re looking to do.  I suggest getting some (FOSS) podcast creation/conversion software to help with this.